# FireStore query with array-contains, search for the whole word

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the new `array-contains` query, but I have a problem...

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it is the normal behaviour...
If I have an array with this value

```
['aaa:12431']
```

and I search for the string `aaa:523`, FireStore returns me the object with `aaa:12431`...

**My question is:**
Does the query `array-contains` searches the whole word or the also part of the word?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore only performs queries for exact matches of data inside arrays using arrayContains.